# How could a user with 1 rep earn the gold Socratic badge?

Tags: bug, status-bydesign

[How could a user with 1 rep earn the gold Socratic badge?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/help/badges/124/socratic) (Scroll down) Surely this is some kind of weird error?

Answer (score 13):

The user you're referring to is currently suspended. He earned the gold Socratic badge before his suspension, at which point he had many thousands of rep, but his rep is set to 1 for the duration of his suspension. You can still see on his profile that he has posted a great many questions.